# How to retrieve sum of 5 top score from a table in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am working on a project where i need to extract the sum of top 5 score for every team sorted   in descending order from a table.

Here is the table structure

[image]

Can anyone help me for this query

Thanks

Comment: Do a subselect that selects the top five, then in the outer select, do a sum on them. You'll need some grouping in there too - can you make a start on this, and edit that into your question? 'Tis good practice! (Bonus points for you if you make a SQL Fiddle with some test data).

Comment: To get the top 5 in the first place, search SO for the tags `[mysql] [greatest-n-per-group]`. MySQL doesn't have a built-in `TOP 5` operator, you need to use the approaches in these answers to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT team_id AS  `team` , (

  SELECT SUM( score ) 
  FROM  `table` 
  WHERE team_id =  `team` 
  ORDER BY score DESC 
  LIMIT 5
) AS  `score` 

FROM  `table` 
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY  `score`  DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sum(score) as total
FROM 
   (SELECT score FROM your_table ORDER BY by score DESC LIMIT 1,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 0;
foreach($this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM scores DESC LIMIT 5") as $rows){
   $count += $rows; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `foo` with your name.

```
SELECT team_id, SUM(score) AS `score`
FROM `foo`
WHERE
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM `foo` AS t1 
  WHERE t1.score >= `foo`.score) <= 5
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY `score` DESC;
```